# Set a custom alarm / browser entire storage on Motorola Moto G5 / Android 7.0

Tags: 7.0-nougat, motorola-moto-g, alarm, ringtone, motorola-moto-g5

I've been using Moto E3 and G4 before and had absolutely no problems in using custom / own alarm tones on these devices / Android versions (on both Android 6, 7.0 and 7.1 in case of G4).

Now, I have purchased Moto G5 and whenever I go to *Clock > Alarm > [alarm] > Ringtone > Your sounds > Add new* some kind of weird file browsers opens that allows me to pick alarm ringtones from only: "Audio" and "Downloads" folders giving me "Recent" and "OneDrive" options in addition.

[image]

How can I select alarm ringtone from (system default?) "Alarms" folder? Or how can I force Clock app to use different file browser (i.e. system "Files Manager" or custom "Solid File Explorer"), which allows me to select a file from any folder?

Am I limited only to above mentioned folders and must copy my alarm ringtone to i.e. "Download" folder in order to use a custom alarm ringtone on Moto G5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "weird" file manager, click on the ellipses in the top right and choose *Show internal storage*.

[image]

Now you should have "Internal Storage" available in the hamburger menu (three horizontal bars) in the left.

[image]

You can now browse your internal storage and choose the custom alarm tone which you want to make your alarm tone and it should be applied.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer that actually did solve my problem. I allowed myself to change title, add some screenshots and modify your own answer a little bit to make it more complex.