# How to get Android 7.1 on Moto G5?

Tags: updates, 7.0-nougat, motorola-moto-g, 7.1-nougat, motorola-moto-g5

As (partially) mentioned [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/195097/20449), I've been using Moto G4 prior to purchasing Moto G5. On Moto G4 I went from Android 6.0 through 7.0 to 7.1.

I assume that Moto G5 is a successor (next generation) of Moto G4. Correct me, if I'm wrong. If so, then why am I still on Android 7.0 or how to trigger immediate update to 7.1 or 8.0?

I assumed that having newer phone = *newer or at least the same* system version. I'd never expect newer phone having older system version than its one year older predecessor. What am I missing?

Comment: The age of a phone matters, however often the phone that was sold more often gets the update earlier (at least with Motorola/Lenovo). The G5 was AFAIR not sold as good as the G4.

Comment: I have returned G5 and replaced it with E4. However, your comment sounds like a perfect answer to the question (actually the answer on "How to get..." is "You can't and you won't") so consider filling up an answer, so I can accept it and bring you some rep.

Answer (score 0):

LineageOS cedrid gives me android 11 on a Moto G5.

Full installation and download information is available here:
https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/cedric/

I have not had any issues with unstable apps.  If you want to use banking apps in the USA you might have some issues, but I have been able to run them with Magisk installed and the Universal SafetyNet Fix.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).